# Two app installed in my device while running android application

Tags: java, android

I have developed an android application using Eclipse.While running the application, there will be two application installed in my device.I really have no idea why this is happened.Please do anyone have idea about this issue?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There can be multiple causes for this issue.

This issue can happen if you have declared multiple **intent-filters** for making the Activity as launcher in your manifest file.

OR

There can be 2 applications with different **packagenames** but same application name in your device.

More information can be given after checking your manifest file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi Aneel if that helped you, please accept the ans, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have one more manifest file somewhere (may be in a library) having an  LAUNCHER intent filter for an activity. Removing the intent filter should solve this.